# Trying to get data to display in my listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, file-io

I've been trying to practice with data binding and file IO concepts and for that I wrote this simple application that reads a 2 column, 5 row .csv file and displays the contents to a Listview in WPF with the feature that I can change the values of the 2nd column in my Listview (like a 2 way binding).

I have not been able to get any information to display in my window. I only get the column headers that I define in my MainWindow.xaml but none of the data binding is working.

Here is my code for the View Model and reading the file

```
namespace WpfPreview
{

public class LoadMovieData : BindableObject // My Data Context?
{
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    private double year; public double Year { get { return year; } set { year = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Year"); } }
}


class ViewModel : BindableObject
{
    private List<LoadMovieData> obsMovies = new List<LoadMovieData>();
    public List<LoadMovieData> ObsMovies
    {
        get { return obsMovies; }
        set { obsMovies = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ObsMovies"); }
    }



    public void ReadFile()
    {

            string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\Param\\Desktop", "excel.csv"); // Get filepath

            using (var csvReader = new StreamReader(filepath)) // using this filepath
            {
                csvReader.ReadLine();       // read first line (headers)
                csvReader.ReadLine();       // read first line of row data

                while (!csvReader.EndOfStream) // while not end of file
                {
                    var words = csvReader.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList(); // read line to list of columns
                    var x = new LoadMovieData()  // new instance of data class
                    {
                        MovieName = words[0],
                        Year = Convert.ToDouble(words[1])
                    };

                    ObsMovies.Add(x); // add instance of data class to list variable

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I'm not sure if my terms are correct. I am trying to follow the MVVM pattern.  My codebehind for the window is this:

```
namespace WpfPreview
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
}
```

and here is my XAML part:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPreview.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:me="clr-namespace:WpfPreview"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="White">

        <ListView x:Name="MovieListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObsMovies}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" Background="Transparent">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Movie Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObsMovies.MovieName}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Year" Width="60">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObsMovies.Year}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

I am very new to working with file IO and data binding/data context. I am sure there is an obvious mistake somewhere and that what I'm trying to do could be done in a much easier/less complicated way.  Please feel free to give me suggestions to restructure my code.

Comment: Where do you call `ReadFile`?

Comment: Oh.  I haven't called the file anywhere. I'm not sure where I can place the call in regards to MVVM.

Comment: Sometimes what I do is I add a load method to my view model and call that from the view in the `WindowLoaded` event. It should break the pattern.

Comment: Currently, I can't even access the ReadFile() member when I type ViewModel with a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally put my data loading code in my ViewModel constructor.  Also, without an access modifier, your ViewModel class is private I believe, so you will not be able to call anything from outside the class. Consider making it `public`.

It looks like your obsMovies list should be an `ObservableCollection`.  The value of obsMovies implements PropertyChanged notification, but if you add an item to it, the collection does not notify the UI that its collection has changed.

## Change this:

```
private List<LoadMovieData> obsMovies = new List<LoadMovieData>();
public List<LoadMovieData> ObsMovies
{
    get { return obsMovies; }
    set { obsMovies = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ObsMovies"); }
}
```

## To this:

```
private ObservableCollection<LoadMovieData> obsMovies = new ObservableCollection<LoadMovieData>();
public ObservableCollection<LoadMovieData> ObsMovies
{
    get { return obsMovies; }
    set { obsMovies = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ObsMovies"); }
}
```

You will have to import System.Collections.ObjectModel to make use of it.

Also, it looks like your bindings may not be quite right.  Try using the following instead:

```
 <ListView.View>
     <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Movie Name">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObsMovies.MovieName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Year" Width="60">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObsMovies.Year}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

The above bindings omit the ObsMovies in the TextBlock bindings.  Since each rows DataContext is one of the items in the collection, there is no need to have the collection referenced in the binding.  Just have the binding path start at the datacontext level (in this case ObsMovies).

Lastly, as promised, a sample implementation of DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ObsMovies}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Year}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Year"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MovieName}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Movie Name"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

To have textboxes to allow for editing of items, in the listView example, replace the TextBlocks with TextBoxes, and for the DataGrid, specify a DataGridTemplateColumn and put a TextBox in the template:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Property}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: ok, it it works now.  The data is showing up in the window.  But I am not able to edit the 2nd column cells yet.  I set my binding Mode to 2 way for the 2nd column but I can't get a text cursor to appear for edit. Do I maybe need to use a data grid instad of listview for that?

Comment: You have the cell template for both columns set to TextBlock.  That is a display only control.  For editing, you will need a TextBox or similar control.  You *can* use a DataGrid, and it would make column definitions easier (although not for editing text properties).  I will post an example in a minute or two.